# Lightswitch, separated assembly for domain service and model - possible bug?

Tags: ria, visual-studio-lightswitch

I try implement custom RIA service which I want to use as external data source in Lightswitch (version 2011). My service uses Entity framework model and domain service. These are in separated class library projects (Model.dll and Service.dll). Lightswitch application is in separated solution.

When I attempt add my RIA service as data source to Lightswitch, following error occurs:

> The type Service.DomainService1 could not be loaded. The assembly
>   containing the class may be missing or may have additional references
>   which are missing.

Can it be Lightswitch bug?

Thanks for response.